# Modulo 2 arithmetics in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-computation

I'm working on transformation polynomial systems over GF(2^N) to GF(2). In a process of transformation I need to do lots of modulo 2 computations like summing and multiplying matrices.

So is there way to sum and multiply matrices using modulo 2 arithmetics in Sympy?

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck with sympy's [trunc()](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=trunc#sympy.polys.polytools.trunc) function:

```
from sympy import *
var('x:z')
y=25*x+12
z=trunc(y,2) # z=x
```