# Modulo computations in Sympy fail

Tags: python, sympy, modular-arithmetic

I have a computation in Sympy, which I want to be modulo 2.
However, if I just write

```
from sympy.abc import x
(((x + 1) % 2) + 1) % 2
```

Then this has the output `Mod(Mod(x + 1, 2) + 1, 2)`, i.e. the two `+1` do not vanish. Even calling `.simplify()` does not have the desired effect.

Another post ([Modulo 2 arithmetics in SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660852/modulo-2-arithmetics-in-sympy)) suggested `sympy.trunc`. But this function does not work if the expression is integer.
I even tried `sympy.trunc(sympy.sympify(1),2)`, but this still raised an Error.

So how do I get a modulo function that works on integers and all coefficients?

PS: I am aware that this is a basic question, and I was confused, that I could not find an answer.

Comment: The modulo operation works. It’s simplifying that apparently doesn’t. You may wanna [file a feature request](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new).

Comment: I opened issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to handle this is to use Poly with the modulus flag:

```
>>> Poly(x + 1, x, modulus=2) + Poly(1, x, modulus=2)
Poly(x, x, modulus=2)
```